# Different foreach loops depending on if statment

Tags: php

In PHP Is it possible to use different if statements to decide which foreach loop to run to avoid writing out the same code.

```
if($myval == 1)
foreach ($student as $member) // to display just students

elseif($myval == 2)
foreach ($staff as $member)  // to display just staff

elseif($myval == 3)
foreach ($sessional as $member)  // to display just sessional

elseif($myval == 0)
foreach ($allmembers as $member)  // to display all
..then print out either just student, or staff, or sessional records
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's possible. You can have a common variable like how you have common `$member`:

```
if($myval == 1)
  $members = $student; // to display just students

elseif($myval == 2)
  $members = $staff;  // to display just staff

elseif($myval == 3)
  $members = $sessional;  // to display just sessional

elseif($myval == 0)
  $members = $allmembers;  // to display all

// ultimately foreach
foreach ($members as $member)  // finally run just once
```

A better way will be using `switch` cases... ☺

Comment: But he could have different for loop code for different if statements so using common variable doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @SatishSaini The OP clearly says there's only one function... That's why. *`foreach loop to run to avoid writing out the same code.`*

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$loopArr` variable to store the temporary data based on the switch case value.

```
$loopArr = array();

switch($myval) {
    case 0: $loopArr = $allmembers;
        break;
    case 1: $loopArr = $student;
        break;
    case 2: $loopArr = $staff;
        break;
    case 3: $loopArr = $sessional;
        break;
    default: $loopArr = array();
}

foreach ($loopArr as $member) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks this looks like the best solution, but I cant seem to get it working. should it break after every argument?